# configuring UART as FIQ

Tags: arm

I am working on lpc2468 and using **UART0 of the controller for communication with sim300 gprs 
module**. Sometimes if i send a command for reading the signal strength of the sim the input I

receive is not correct. After looking upon the problem I found the problem that sometimes

*when the UART is receiving information at same time the timer gets called and the software 
goes to the timer block. in that duration some bytes sent by the module gets missed.* To

prevent this i want to configure UART0 as FIQ i.e. interrupt having highest priority. can I

configure UART0 as FIQ.If yes How?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From LPC2048 data sheet,

> The ARM processor core has two interrupt inputs called Interrupt
> ReQuest (IRQ) and Fast  Interrupt ReQuest (FIQ). The VIC takes 32
> interrupt request inputs which can be  programmed as FIQ or vectored
> IRQ types. The programmable assignment scheme  means that priorities
> of interrupts from the various peripherals can be dynamically
> assigned and adjusted.

So you need to find out where are the programmable registers of the Interrupt controller and change the interrupt type of UART to FIQ.

If you have simulation support, then see [this](http://www.keil.com/dd/vtr/4181/7875.htm) to know how to change interrupt types and priorities.